# Android center the Image Inside match_parent

Tags: android, imageview

Center the Image Inside ImageView which set width and height to match_parent

ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/iv_Image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
```

scaleType set to 'matrix' because of using Zoom and Touch Events.

How to Center the Image Inside ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the device Width and Height

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

Calculate the ImageView CenterX using image_width

```
float imageCenterX = (displayMetrics.widthPixels - image_width) / 2;
```

Calculate the ImageView CenterY using image_height

```
float imageCenterY = image_height > displayMetrics.heightPixels/2 ? 0 : dpHeight/2
```

Set New Matrix to Image

```
Matrix matrix_ = new Matrix();
matrix_.postTranslate(imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
ivImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix_);
```